# Stuck on Finding Nilpotent Inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

$A \in \mathcal{L}(V,V)$. $\dim(V)=n$. $A$ is nilpotent, meaning $A^k=0$ for some $k > 0$ . We can assume all eigenvalues of $A$ are $0$ and $A^n=0$

Let $M=\beta_0 I+\beta_1 A+\cdots+\beta_r A^r$, $r \in \mathbb{Z+}, \beta_0 \neq 0$ ($r$ is an arbitrary positive integer). Find its inverse and show it is invertible.

I can't seem to figure out the inverse no matter how hard I try not even for small examples.

Consider the example:
Suppose $n=4$. Thus we know that $A^4=0$. Let all $\beta=1$ for simplicity.

Suppose $r=2$ ($r$ is any positive integer)

Then $M=I+A+A^2$.
I proposed the inverse is $N=I-A+A^2$.

But, $MN=(I+A+A^2)(I-A+A^2)=I+A+A^2-A-A^2-A^3+A^2-A^3+A^4$

This equals
$MN=I+A^2+A^4=I+A^2$ not I as desired. So, I'm really stuck as to how to find the inverse.

Also I know that $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$.  Why does this imply that $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $M=\beta_0 I+\beta_1 A+\cdots+\beta_r A^r$, $r \in \mathbb{Z+}, \beta_0 \neq 0$ and hence it is invertible?

Like I somewhat see it because $\beta_0 \neq 0$ but I don't really understand formally why $0$ is not an eigenvalue.
If $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$ does this mean $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $A^2$, etc.. $A^r$ and thus it is the only eigenvalue of $\beta_1 A + \cdots + \beta_r A^r$?

My main concern is with finding the inverse but I am stuck. Thanks.

Comment: Hints: (1) Show that $I + A$ is invertible using the formula for a geometric series: $\frac{1}{1 + x} = \sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^n x^n$. (2) Note that $\beta_1 A + \cdots + \beta_r A^r$ is still nilpotent by the binomial formula since powers of $A$ commute with each other.

Comment: I didn't really understand. Say I am able to show $I+A$ is invertible, how does this show $M=\beta A+....\beta_rA^r$ is invertible? Also how do I go about finding the inverse for $M$?

Comment: Also I didn't understand the last sentence at all about $\beta_1 A+...\beta_r A^r$ being nilpotent? how is the sum nilpotent by binomial formula? Also how does this help me find the inverse. I am lost.

Comment: In (1) you show that $I+X$ is invertible for an arbitrary nilpotent matrix $X$. In (2), you prove that $\beta_1 A + \cdots + \beta_r A^r$ is nilpotent, so you can apply (1) with $X = \beta_1 A + \cdots + \beta_r A^r$. To show that $\beta_1 A + \cdots + \beta_r A^r$ is nilpotent, raise it to the power $k$ (where $A^k = 0$) and expand using the binomial formula.

Comment: I see it makes sense now. So to show $\beta_1A+....\beta_rA^r$ is nilpotent, I have to show that $(\beta_1A+....\beta_rA^r)^k=0$? Is that correct?

Comment: This might sound dumb but I don't really know how to use binomial theorem for it since there are $r$ terms instead of two terms in summation raised to power $k$? How do I expand this using the binomial theorem? that would be really helpful then I can take it from there I think

Comment: Yes, that's right. And you're right, I should have said the multinomial formula. The key thing to note is that each term in the expansion will have at least $k$ copies of $A$, and since $A^k = 0$...

Comment: I'll try it with a small example. I'm trying to see what you mean by at least k copies of $A$. I could raise it to power $n$ instead of $k$ right since we know $A^n=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Represent your matrix as $\beta_0(I+AB)$ where $B$ commutes with $A$. In fact $B=\frac{1}{\beta_0}(\beta_1 I+\beta_2A+...)$. Then the inverse is $\frac 1{\beta_0}(I-AB+A^2B^2-...\pm A^{n-1}B^{n-1})$. To check, just multiply that matrix by $\beta_0(1+AB)$.

Comment: Hi @JCAA I'll try it now, I'll let you know if I run into any problems. Does B commuting with A mean AB=BA?

Comment: Yes, $AB=BA$, you can check that it holds. Then, by the way, $(AB)^n=A^nB^n=0$ which is used in the proof,

Comment: Oh so it is used in the proof to show that what you gave is the inverse you mean?

Comment: Right.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I am confused actually why is the matrix $\beta_{0}(1+AB)$. Why is there a $1$? Suppose all $\beta=1$ and we have $M=I+A+A^2$. But in your case we have $M=(1+AB)=(1+A(I+A))=1+A+A^2. So the one should be identity instead?

Comment: $1$ is  $I$, the identity matrix.I changed it in the answer.

Comment: Thanks I'm trying to show it is the inverse right now although I'm struggling a bit with the algebra. I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: Im confused I can't prove it at all. Suppose $n=4$ so $A^4=0$ and$ M=I+A+A^2$. By your statement $(I+A+A^2)(I-A(I+A)+A^2(I+A)^2-A^3(I+A)^3)=I$ but I can't get it to work out at all? how do you get this to work out/how did you come up with this?

Comment: I got to show that case was the identity. But how do I do it generally? the expression is very messy. Could you add to your answer the beginning of showing it like the first couple of steps, it would be really helpful? Thanks.

Comment: It's neater to write $M=\beta_0(I-C)$ where $C=-\frac{1}{\beta_0}(\beta_1 A+\beta_2A^2+\cdots+\beta^rA^r)$, so that $C^k=0$ and $M^{-1}=\frac 1{\beta_0}(I-C)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\beta_0}(I+C+C^2+\cdots+C^{k-1})$.

Comment: It is not  "neater" because the fact that $C^k=0$ needs to be proved anyway.